# && is breaking the page in WordPress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I added this to my WordPress [page](http://mediaclear.net/dobake/dobake-news-delivered-fresh/)

```
if (script.readyState && script.onload!==null){
    script.onreadystatechange= function () {
        if (this.readyState == 'complete') mce_preload_check();
    }
}
```

and the `&&` is being turned to

```
if (script.readyState &#038;&#038; script.onload!==null){
```

I pasted this in WordPress HTML view and I made sure this was fine but WordPress keeps displaying this. How to address this?

Comment: are you putting this JS code in a post? or are you editing the theme's header.php file?

Comment: And you want this to be shown to the user in a post or is this for execution for your own site?

Comment: I actually didnt add it...but i was responsible for fixing it

Comment: i am responsible for fixing the errors, but i originally didnt put the js in the post....i was thinking of moving it out into an external js file though

Comment: What about uploading the javascript file to another service and importing it to Wordpress from there? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65674751/5802289

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to disable WP's autoformatting. WP will auto format even in the html editor, and the spaces and line breaks will break your javascript.

Use this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-no-format/

**Update 4/08/2015: plugin is dated but still works for me.**

**This also works: add the plugin directly to functions.php** and bracket the your javascript in `<!-- noformat on -->` and `<!-- noformat off -->` tags

Add to functions.php file:

```
function newautop($text)
{
    $newtext = "";
    $pos = 0;

    $tags = array('<!-- noformat on -->', '<!-- noformat off -->');
    $status = 0;

    while (!(($newpos = strpos($text, $tags[$status], $pos)) === FALSE))
    {
        $sub = substr($text, $pos, $newpos-$pos);

        if ($status)
            $newtext .= $sub;
        else
            $newtext .= convert_chars(wptexturize(wpautop($sub)));      //Apply both functions (faster)

        $pos = $newpos+strlen($tags[$status]);

        $status = $status?0:1;
    }

    $sub = substr($text, $pos, strlen($text)-$pos);

    if ($status)
        $newtext .= $sub;
    else
        $newtext .= convert_chars(wptexturize(wpautop($sub)));      //Apply both functions (faster)

    //To remove the tags
    $newtext = str_replace($tags[0], "", $newtext);
    $newtext = str_replace($tags[1], "", $newtext);

    return $newtext;
}

function newtexturize($text)
{
    return $text;   
}

function new_convert_chars($text)
{
    return $text;   
}

remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
add_filter('the_content', 'newautop');

remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');
add_filter('the_content', 'newtexturize');

remove_filter('the_content', 'convert_chars');
add_filter('the_content', 'new_convert_chars');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to make a [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). In this example, the shortcode will only be printed if it contains the attributes `x` and `y`, e.g.: `[myscript x="10" y="20"]`. I'm using a simple script that shows a JS alert dialog with the attributes values.

```
add_shortcode( 'myscript', 'sample_shortcode_so_6195635' );

function sample_shortcode_so_6195635( $atts, $content = null )
{   
    if( isset( $atts['x'] ) && isset( $atts['y'] ) )
    {
        $x = $atts['x'];
        $y = $atts['y'];

        // See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc
        $html = <<<HTML
        <button onclick="myalert()">Show Shortcode Atts</button>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function myalert()
        {
            if( $x < 10 && $y < 20 )
                alert( 'X less than 10 and Y less than 20' );
            else
                alert( 'other' );
        }
        </script>   
HTML;
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the following lines (either via inline PHP (you need a plugin for that) or in "functions.php") are being executed on your page:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize' );
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_chars' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code snippet to your script

```
<script>
  function logicalAND($opA, $opB) {
    if($opA) {
      if($opB) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  if (logicalAND(script.readyState, script.onload !== null)){
    ...
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).