# Wordpress changing "&&" into "&#038;&"

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, include, character

I'm using the `PHP` include function to include static `PHP` and `JS` content within my Wordpress pages (made possible with the ezPHP plugin). The PHP is working fine, but the JS isn't. I'm getting "illegal character" errors. Every instance of `&&` is being changed to the html code for `&&` (I tried including it here, but it renders the character). To try to fix this, I've (1) disabled Wordpress's WYSIWYG editor for my user, (2) under `Settings` > `Writing`, unchecked "WordPress should correct invalidly nested XHTML automatically", and (3) added the following code to my theme's `function.php`:

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');
```

Still I'm getting this error. I'm guessing it has something to do with Wordpress's `esc_html()` function, but I don't know how exactly.

Comment: Are you using the `wp_enqueue_script` function to include JS and tacking a querystring onto the `$src` param?

Answer (score 1):

You can upload the javascript file to another service and import it to Wordpress from there by just adding an HTML block.

```
<script
   type="text/javascript"
   src="https://whatever-url-this-is/myjavascriptfile.js"
></script>
```

Apparently, Github does not support that anymore, but there are some workarounds [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18049842/5802289) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20311329/5802289).